# width mismatch in assignment; target has 10 bits, source has 8 bits error

Tags: vhdl, vivado, digital-logic

I try to write VHDL code in Vivado to show multiply 8 bit number by 1,2,3,4.
i got the error in line (y <= ..) :
" width mismatch in assignment; target has 10 bits, source has 8 bits error in vhdl"
i dont understand whats the problem

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;



entity multiplies is
    Port ( sel : in STD_LOGIC_vector (1 downto 0);
           x : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
           y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0));
end multiplies;

architecture Behavioral of multiplies is

component multi
port (i0: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
      X : in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
      z: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0));
END COMPONENT;

signal A2: std_logic_vector(9 downto 0); 
signal A3: std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
signal A4: std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);

begin

with sel select

Y<= (x) when "00",
    A2 when  "01",
    A3 when "10",
    A4 when others;
  
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Vhdl is a very explicit and low level language. It doesn't interpret the data types and convert automatically. I.e. if the sizes are different, you'll have to connect thing up yourself

Answer (score 1):

Port `x` is 7:0 whereas port `y` is 9:0.

So you can't assign `x` to `y` directly in your with-select clause, you correctly get an error.

That part of the clause can instead be:

```
Y  <=  "00" & x  when "00",
       A2        when "01",
       A3        when "10",
       A4        when others;
```